# plotly express scatter plot python

Tags: python, express, plotly, scatter

I have a problem with plotly I want to make a scatter plot
I want to make this same graph but with other circle shape for ind1, tringale for ind2 and the color is according to the type

here is my my code  code for your help:

```
data = {'ind1':[4,8,12,13,22,23],'ind2':[1,5,9,60,90,30],'type':['reg1','reg2','reg1','reg1','reg2','reg1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
fig = px.scatter(df, x=df['ind1'],y= df['ind2'],color='type')
fig.show()
```

the graph that I compe to make and like the one in my answer but instead of having the shape of point in the two indicator I want to make the difference by changing the shape of the indicator 2 in triangle and keep the color by type like c is the case in this figure

[image]

Comment: Each scatter point depends on both ind1 and ind2. So, what does it mean that ind1 should be represented by circles and ind2 by triangles?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand how the desired graph should look like,

but here is an example of [styling symbols with plotly express](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter)

Note, that in order for this to work you need to pass a **list** `list_of_symbols` to `symbol` variable (in this case it is the name of the column in `df` containting that list) and a **dictionary** `dict` with `dict.keys() = list_of_symbols`, while values for desired symbols you can [look up here](https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/#custom-marker-symbols)
[image: exemplar graph with marker_size = 15]

```
data = {'ind1':[4,8,12,13,22,23],'ind2':[1,5,9,60,90,30],'type':['reg1','reg2','reg1','reg1','reg2','reg1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
fig = px.scatter(df, x='ind1', y= 'ind2', color='type', 
                 symbol = 'ind2',
                 symbol_map = {1:'diamond-open-dot',
                               5:'diamond-open',
                               9:'diamond',
                               60:'cross-open-dot',
                               90:'triangle-right-open-dot',
                               30:'hexagon'})
fig.show()
```

Comment: the graph that I compe to make and like the one in my answer but instead of having the shape of point in the two indicator I want to make the difference by changing the shape of the indicator 2 in triangle and keep the color by type like c is the case in this figure
thank you

Comment: So, you want ind1 and ind2 as separate y(x) functions and not ind2(ind1) as it is right now?

Comment: Please, try to rephrase what is your goal and make another exemplar graph. Because it is still not clear for me.

Comment: the datframe becomes like this on the time in x and in y the two indicators chasur indicator is represented by a shape (ind1: circle and ind2: triangle) and the color of the two shapes depends on the type. THis is the dataframe : data = {'time':[1,2,3,4,4,8],'ind1':[4,8,12,13,22,23],'ind2':[1,5,9,60,90,30],'type':['reg1','reg2','reg1','reg1','reg2','reg1']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)